# Создать игру “Угадай число"

Tags: python

Сначала нужно угадать число в диапазоне от 1 до 2, затем от 1 до 3 и так далее. Использовать модуль random. Игра должна быть бесконечной. Если пользователь не угадал число, он начинает сначала (угадать число от 1 до 2).
Как правильно написать код?

```
from random import randint
A=randint(1,2)
B=randint(1,3)
C=randint(1,4)
D=randint(1,5)

while True:
    K = input("Угадайте целое число от 1 до 2:")
    if int(K) == A:
        print("Вы угадали")
        F = input("Угадайте целое число от 1 до 3:")
    elif int(F) == B:
        print("Вы угадали")
        G = input("Угадайте целое число от 1 до 4:")
    elif int(G) == C:
        print("Вы угадали")
    else:
        print("Попробуй еще раз")
```

Comment: что значит "правильно"? Есть примерно 100500 вариантов написать "правильно".

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```
from random import randint

num_max = 2
r = randint(1, num_max) # берём диапазон от 1 до num_max
while True: # создаём бесконечный цикл
    num = int(input(f"Угадайте число от 1 до {num_max}: "))
    if num == r:
        num_max += 1
        r = randint(1, num_max)
        print("Вы угадали!")
    else:
        print("Вы не угадали :(")
        print("Попробуйте ещё раз")
        num_max = 2
```

Comment: Код неверный, поправьте. Для контроля выводите num_max перед генерацией случайного числа.

Comment: это никак не повлияет не его корректность.

Comment: Это поможет вам увидеть некорректность. Что будет генерироваться в r после того, кака человек угадал в первый раз?

Comment: ааа понял только что